# Generar reporte en txt con consulta en SQL Server desde PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php5

De la función siguiente queryMonth deseo generar los resultados de la consulta en un TXT.

Función queryMonth:

```
public function queryMonth($fecha1,$fecha2)
 {


$res = array();
$rowres = "";


$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,"with cte AS ( 
                                select DISTINCT c.CodeCompany as CompanyCode,
                                CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112) as Period,
                                                    a.idClave as EmployeID,
                                 c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as EmployeName,
                                                    d.idDepto as Depto,
                                                 t.HorasAlMes as PlanWorkHoursMonth,
           SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24) as ActualWorkHoursMonth


    from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
                         JOIN tblDepto    d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
                         JOIN tblTurno    t ON c.fkTurno=t.idTurno

         where fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fecha1." 00:00:00',103) and 
            CONVERT(DATETIME,'".$fecha2." 23:59:59',103)and c.fkStatus !=1 

        group by
        c.CodeCompany, 
        a.idClave, 
        d.idDepto,
        t.HorasAlMes,
        c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos)

select  CompanyCode,Period, EmployeID, EmployeName,Depto,PlanWorkHoursMonth,ActualWorkHoursMonth,


 OvertimeHoursMonth=
  case 
    when ActualWorkHoursMonth>PlanWorkHoursMonth then abs(PlanWorkHoursMonth-ActualWorkHoursMonth)

  else 0

  end,

LeaveHoursMonth=

  case 
    when ActualWorkHoursMonth<PlanWorkHoursMonth then abs(PlanWorkHoursMonth-ActualWorkHoursMonth)
  else 0

  end



from cte");



if( $stmt === false) {
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

Aquí se supone que se debería generar el TXT
    $stmt trae el resultado de la consulta

```
$archivo = 'archivo.txt';

$handler = fopen($archivo,'a');
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   fwrite($handler,$row['CompanyCode']);
   fwrite($handler,$row['Period']);
}
fclose($handler);
```

Con esto se visualizan los datos en una tabla en HTML

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$rowres .= '<tr class="success">
    <td>'.$row["CompanyCode"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["Period"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["EmployeID"]. '</td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EmployeName"]). '</td>
    <td>'.$row["Depto"]. '</td>
    <td>'.$row["PlanWorkHoursMonth"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["ActualWorkHoursMonth"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["OvertimeHoursMonth"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["LeaveHoursMonth"].'</td>

   </tr>';
}


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
return $rowres;


}
```

Form con los POST de donde se envian las fechas: fecha1 y Fecha2

```
  if (isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2']))
  {


   echo $db->queryMonth($_POST['date1'],$_POST['date2']); 


  }else
  {
    echo "<p> Coloque fecha de inicio y fecha de fin </p>";
  }


  ?>
```

La sintaxis para generar el TXT:

```
  $archivo = 'archivo.txt';

  $handler = fopen($archivo,'a');
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    fwrite($handler,$row['CompanyCode']);
    fwrite($handler,$row['Period']);
 }
 fclose($handler);
```

Sin embargo no se esta generando el TXT.

Sin embargo si pongo las siguientes lineas de código en la parte superior de donde hago la conexión a la BDD
genera un TXT guardando el código fuente de la página html, como se muestra en la imagen a continuación:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código que descarga un TXT con el contenido de la imagen anterior

```
$archivo = 'archivo.txt';
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$archivo);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

include($archivo);
```

Código de la conexion a la BDD y de la funcion queryMonth

```
$archivo = 'archivo.txt';
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$archivo);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

include($archivo);




class database {

private $conn;
private $serverName;
private $connectionInfo;

public function __construct()
{
$serverName = "000.000.00.00"; // Ip de conexion
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"bdd", "blabla"=>"user", "PWD"=>"contraseña"); // Cadena de conexión

$this->conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if( $this->conn === false ) {

die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  //  muestra mensaje si falla
}

}




public function  queryMonth  ($fecha1,$fecha2)
{


$res = array();
$rowres = "";


echo $fecha1;

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,"with cte AS ( 
                                    select DISTINCT c.CodeCompany as CompanyCode,
                                    CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112) as Period,
                                                        a.idClave as EmployeID,
                                     c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as EmployeName,
                                                        d.idDepto as Depto,
                                                     t.HorasAlMes as PlanWorkHoursMonth,
               SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24) as ActualWorkHoursMonth


        from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
                             JOIN tblDepto    d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
                             JOIN tblTurno    t ON c.fkTurno=t.idTurno

             where fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fecha1." 00:00:00',103) and 
                CONVERT(DATETIME,'".$fecha2." 23:59:59',103)and c.fkStatus !=1 

            group by
            c.CodeCompany, 
            a.idClave, 
            d.idDepto,
            t.HorasAlMes,
            c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos)

select  CompanyCode,Period, EmployeID, EmployeName,Depto,PlanWorkHoursMonth,ActualWorkHoursMonth,


OvertimeHoursMonth=
    case 
        when ActualWorkHoursMonth>PlanWorkHoursMonth then abs(PlanWorkHoursMonth-ActualWorkHoursMonth)

    else 0

    end,

LeaveHoursMonth=

    case 
        when ActualWorkHoursMonth<PlanWorkHoursMonth then abs(PlanWorkHoursMonth-ActualWorkHoursMonth)
    else 0

    end



 from cte");


if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}




$archivo= 'archivo.txt'; 


$handler = fopen($archivo,'w');
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    fwrite($handler,$row["CompanyCode"]);
    fwrite($handler,$row["Period"]);
}
fclose($handler);





while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$rowres .= '<tr class="success">
    <td>'.$row["CompanyCode"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["Period"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["EmployeID"]. '</td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EmployeName"]). '</td>
    <td>'.$row["Depto"]. '</td>
    <td>'.$row["PlanWorkHoursMonth"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["ActualWorkHoursMonth"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["OvertimeHoursMonth"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["LeaveHoursMonth"].'</td>

  </tr>';


}


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);   
return $rowres;





}
```

}

?>

Código del HTML de donde se envia las fechas, fecha 1 y fecha2

```
<div class="main">

<div class="main-inner">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="span12">            

            <div class="widget ">
                <a name="head"></a>     
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                    <h3> R.1 </h3>
                </div> <!-- /widget-header -->

                <div class="widget-content">                    
                    <div class="tabbable">
                    <br>        
                            <form id="edit-profile"  method="POST"  action ="document.php" class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset>                                      

                                    <div class="control-group">                                         

                                        <label class="control-label" for="date1">Fecha Inicio:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text"  id="date1" name="date1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date1'])) echo $_POST['date1']; else 
                                            echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>">    
                                        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

                                            <div class="control-group">                                         
                                        <label class="control-label" for="date2">Fecha Final:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text"  id="date2"  name="date2"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date2'])) echo $_POST['date2']; else 
                                            echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>" >
                                        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

                                     <br />

                                    <div class="form-actions">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar </button> 

                                    </div> <!-- /form-actions -->
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>


 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >


<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>CompanyCode</th>
    <th>Period</th>
    <th>EmployeID</th>
    <th>EmployeName</th>
    <th>Depto</th>
    <th>PlanWorkHoursMonth</th>
    <th>ActualWorkHoursMonth</th>
    <th>OvertimeHoursMonth</th>
    <th>LeaveHoursMonth</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 

<?php 




if (isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2']))
{


echo $db->   queryMonth($_POST['date1'],$_POST['date2']); 






}else
{
    echo "<p> Coloque fecha de inicio y fecha de fin </p>";
}


?>

  </tbody>
</table>


                            </div>

                    </div>


                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>




      </div> <!-- /row -->
    </div> <!-- /container -->      
</div> <!-- /main-inner -->
```

Comment: ¿Qué arroja un `print_r(sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt));`?. Creo que habría sido más útil que pusieras todo el código como lo tienes mostrando la lógica general que sigues, en vez de ir mostrando parte del código y explicando. Aquí parece que hay algo mal puesto en alguna parte, por lo que se podrá ver mejor si pones todo el código seguido. Por ejemplo, desde donde ejecutas la consulta, **no se ve en ningún momento cómo recuperas el resultado de la consulta**, que son los datos que están en juego aquí.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya agrege el código completo

Comment: Hay aquí que no cuadra. Dices: *Código de la conexion a la BDD y de la funcion queryMonth*, y cuando reviso ese código no aparece ninguna función llamada `queryMont`, sino una función llamada `consulta`. Y en la función `queryMonth` que pones al principio de la pregunta no tienes ningún `return`... Creo que lo que tienes es algo de desorden en tu código y por eso no te genera el archivo, sino que te saca código PHP, porque las funciones no están escritas correctamente o porque no las estás llamando como deberías llamarlas.

Comment: Esta llamada que haces aquí: `echo $db->queryMonth($_POST['date1'],$_POST['date2']);` no te devolverá los datos que esperas, si `queryMonth` está escrita como aparece al principio, sin ningún `return`.

Comment: @A. Cedano ya edite el código la consulta se llama queryMonth, en echo $db->queryMonth... Le paso el valor de 2 inputs de tipo texto, la fecha 1 y 2

Comment: En el código PHP/HTML donde llamas a `queryMonth`, ¿donde creas la instancia de la clase a la que pertenece `queryMonth`? Además no puedes llamarla con un `echo` puesto que no retorna nada. Si quieres imprimir algo en pantalla sería algún mensaje con el resultado  final de la creación del archivo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo que hace echo $db->queryMonth($_POST['date1'],$_POST['date2']); 
es imprimir el resultado en una tabla, de lo que esta definido en:
  $rowres .='<tr class="success">
        <td>'.$row["CompanyCode"].' </td>
        <td>'.$row["Period"].' </td>
        <td>'.$row["EmployeID"]. '</td>
        <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EmployeName"]). '</td>
        <td>'.$row["PlanWorkHoursMonth"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["ActualWorkHoursMonth"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["OvertimeHoursMonth"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["LeaveHoursMonth"].'</td>
      </tr>'; return $rowres;

Comment: ¿Y `queryMonth` te imprime esa tabla a la que te refieres?

Comment: @A.Cedano si queryMonth imprime la tabla, pero la idea es generar un TXT

Comment: ¿Y por qué generas una tabla si lo que quieres es generar un `txt`? ¿Por qué no pruebas a comentar toda la parte de la tabla e intentas generar el fichero de este modo: `$archivo = 'archivo.txt';

$handler = fopen($archivo,'a');
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   fwrite($handler,$row['CompanyCode']);
   fwrite($handler,$row['Period']);
}
fclose($handler);`

Comment: @A.Cedano Por que estoy probando si realmente se esta ejecutando la consulta, si ya he hecho la prueba de comentar.... No sé si esta sintaxis es correcta: while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { fwrite($handler,$row['CompanyCode']); fwrite($handler,$row['Period']); }

Comment: Debería serlo. En el `while` es la misma que usas para llenar la tabla, la cual dices que funciona. Y lo del archivo te lo he puesto como lo tenías. ¿No te funcionó ?

Comment: @A.Cedano para llenar la tabla si funciona, pero para escribir sobre el archivo NO

Comment: Tendría que hacer una prueba de concepto... cuando disponga de algo de tiempo reviso tu forma de escribir en el archivo y te comento o te escribo una respuesta. Ahora mismo estaré ocupado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho una prueba de concepto, usando tu mismo código para la creación del archivo.

<kbd>**[VER Y PROBAR AQUÍ](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/a57p-t7be)**</kbd>

El código se ejecuta correctamente, generando un archivo de texto con estos datos:

```
ID   NOMBRE         APELLIDO       
1    Jack           Nicholson      
2    Marlon         Brando         
3    Robert         De Niro        
4    Al             Pacino         
5    Dustin         Hoffman        
6    Jennifer       Jones          
7    Holly          Hunter
```

A continuación enumeraré una de las posibles causas por las que en tu caso podría no estar funcionando:

1. Permisos de lectura/escritura en la carpeta donde intentas crear el archivo.
2. Problemas con la lógica del programa

**Verificar 1**: Puedes (y debes) verificar siempre el resultado de `fopen` antes de intentar escribir en cualquier fichero (ver código de la prueba de concepto):

```
        $handler = fopen($archivo,'w');
        /*Verificamos que el recurso se abrió*/
        if($handler)
        {
            //Operamos con el archivo
            //...
        else
        {
            $txtHTML='No se pudo abrir el archivo';
        }
```

También puedes verificar los permisos directamente en la carpeta. O intentar verificar el resultado de `fwrite`, ya que esta función devuelve `FALSE` cuando ocurre algún problema.

**Verificar 2.** Tendrías que revisar la lógica del programa, depurando los datos de salida. Por ejemplo estas partes esenciales:

```
/*Comentamos el código para depurar*/               
//$handler = fopen($archivo,'a');
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    //fwrite($handler,$row['CompanyCode']);
    //fwrite($handler,$row['Period']);
    echo $row['CompanyCode'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $row['Period'].PHP_EOL;

}
//fclose($handler);
```

Otra cosa podría estarte fastidiando es todo esto antes de la clase `database`. No tiene ningún sentido incluir un archivo de texto en una clase de PHP, ni tampoco tiene sentido imprimir `headers` allí. Ese uso revela un serio problema de lógica en tu programa. Esos headers deberían estar justo antes de dar salida al archivo en sí, no antes de la clase `database`:

```
$archivo = 'archivo.txt';
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$archivo);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

include($archivo);  

class database {
    //... resto del código
```

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es, en vez de ir escribiendo línea por línea, puedes concatenar todo el contenido en una cadena dentro del `while` y luego escribirlo en el archivo usando `file_put_contents`. Algo así más o menos:

```
$archivo = 'archivo.txt';
$newText='';

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $newText.=str_pad($row['CompanyCode'],15);
    $newText.=str_pad($row['Period'],15);
    $newText.=PHP_EOL;
 }

/*Escribimos en el texto concatenado en el archivo*/
file_put_contents($archivo, $newText);


/*
    *Leemos el archivo
    *AQUÍ, Y SÓLO AQUÍ DEBERÍAS PONER LOS header
    *en ningún otro sitio
*/

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$archivo);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));

$txtContent = file_get_contents($archivo);
$txtHTML = htmlentities($txtContent);
print_r($txtHTML);
```

Comment: Sin duda eran los permisos de escritura. Cuando te refieres a los header quedaría de la siguiente manera?

Comment: $archivo = "E:/archivo.txt";
 if (!file_exists($archivo))
     exit("No se encuentra el archivo");
    else
     echo "Se encontro el archivo";
 $handler = fopen($archivo, 'w');
 if ($handler) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {

     $companycode=$row["CompanyCode"];
     $period=$row["Period"];
     $employename=$row["EmployeName"];
     $depto=$row["Depto"];

Comment: fwrite($handler,str_pad($companycode,10));
    fwrite($handler,str_pad($period,10));
    fwrite($handler,str_pad($employename,45));
    fwrite($handler,PHP_EOL);}
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$archivo);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archivo));
    $txtContent = file_get_contents($archivo);
    $txtHTML = htmlentities($txtContent);
    print_r($txtHTML);
    
    }
    
    fclose($handler);
   
}

Comment: Por que sera que el While que imprime los datos en la tabla en HTML ya no se ejecuta; sin embargo si el While lo pongo arriba de donde se crea el archivo si se ejecuta, pero ya no se genera el archivo?

Comment: @NetzaL Si quieres que te cree el archivo, no necesitas usar `if (!file_exists($archivo)) ...`, sino como te lo puse arriba, en la respuesta... `if ($handler){//...Operamos con el archivo` aquí pones el `while` y todo lo relativo a la escritura en el archivo  y al final, pones los `header` e imprimes el archivo si quieres. En cuanto a lo otro que dices que no funciona debe ser por un error de lógica en tu programa. Tendrías que poner todo el código seguido para revisar dónde podría estar el error. También puedes revisar el `error_log`, el cual te dirá cuál es el error que está ocurriendo.

Comment: los headers van dentro del While? la idea es que se vaya creando un archivo independiente por cada ejecución, no sobreescribir el que ya existe.

Comment: @NetzaL Ohhh, es que cada vez aportas elementos nuevos que son determinantes para resolver el problema. ¿Ese detalle de que quieres generar archivos nuevos por cada ejecución qué significa, un archivo por cada iteracción dentro del `while` o un archivo nuevo por cada ejecución del código en sí? Los `headers` deben usarse una sola vez, pero, para más seguridad, ya que dices que quieres crear varios archivos, yo lo haría de otra forma. Lo haría agregando parámetros a los archivos que haya que crear, entre ellos el tipo de archivo indicado en los `header` ...

Comment: ... y claro, habría que modificar los nombres, usando por ejemplo `archivo+fecha_hora_minuto_segundo+.txt`  como nombre de archivo.

Comment: Es un archivo nuevo por cada ejecución del código en sí, el nombre del archivo ya le agrege la fecha es decir: $fechaActual = date("d-m-Y");
$archivo = "H:/archivo-" . $fechaActual . ".txt";  pero lo de un archivo nuevo por cada ejecución del código en sí no sé que parametros van en el header